# CSS hover menu positioning troubles

Tags: css

I'm building a CSS hover menu for my site: http://test.fairfood.org.

I can't seem to figure out how to position each nested ul to display underneath it's parent li. They all show up at the same place. 
The submenus also disappear behind the carrousel even though the nested ul's have position absolute and a high z-index.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest stripping all your style from the ul li elements and just call them like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/MmsVS/

This is the style I use for my own menus.

Comment: Thank you, you're my hero. Saving this as a snippet.